# Taking objects from list only if not empty

Tags: c#, linq

How can I take objects from A only if A is not empty? This is what I am trying, but I realized `q != null` will always be true as A is a List.

```
A.Where(q => q.Id == B.Id && q != null)
```

I need to do the selection in one line only as this is inside a Select Statement.

Comment: _"q != null will always be true"_ - If your list contains reference types, this is an invalid statement. `list.Add(null);`, for example, can insert a null item. Can you clarify your question? You're not taking any items from the list if it's empty.

Comment: Note that you will get a `NullReferenceException` before `q != null` is ever reached because your conditions are in the wrong order.

Comment: As @John mentioned you need to check q != null first only then you have to validate the other condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is empty, `A.Where(...)` will return 0 results. So you're not taking any items from the list if it's empty.

With regards to your comment about `q != null` always being true, that's not correct if your list contains reference types as your list can contain null values:

```
List<string> A = new List<string>();
A.Add(null);
```

Which means that your clause will fail in this case because your conditions are in the wrong order (the null check should come first):

```
A.Where(q => q != null && q.Id == B.Id);
```

You can also write this to use a [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators), but note that if `B.Id` is also null, it will match:

```
A.Where(q => q?.Id == B.Id);
```

In the example above, calling `A.Where(q => q != null && q.Id == B.Id).ToList()` will result in a list with 0 items (because the source list doesn't contain any matching elements).

Answer (score -1):

```
if(A.Count != 0)
    A.Where(q => q.Id == B.Id);
```

or

```
if(A.Any())
    A.Where(q => q.Id == B.Id);
```

or

```
A != null ? A.Where(q => q.Id == B.Id) : return null; //or whatever you want
```

Comment: Please read the last line of the question sir. I need to do it 1 line inside a select statement.

Comment: So you can use ternary operator
    A != null ?  A.Where(q => q.Id == B.Id) : return nul; 
//or return whatever you want

Comment: If there's no null check before, so check it on ternary operator

Comment: The third code example would be useful, if `A` could be `null` (and the entries in the list were not `null` - which is a problem since the OP's data has `null` entries **inside** the list). But the first and second code examples are not useful.